# Merge 2 SELECT statements into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fairly new to SQL and I have wrote 2 different select statements to query my database and I was wondering how I would go about merging them into one SELECT query as they look fairly identical and I'm sure it can be done i'm just scratching my head at the moment and haven't been able to come up with the solution

These are my 2 select statements:

```
select part.Id, part.Name, part.Quantity, 
        part.Cost AS "Individual Part Cost", 
        Quantity * Cost AS"Total Part Cost"
from part, repair
where repair.Id = part.RepairId
and monthname(repair.Date) = "December";
```

```
select SUM(Cost) AS "Total Month Cost", avg(Cost) AS "Average Month Cost"
from part, repair
where repair.Id = part.RepairId
and monthname(repair.Date) = "September"
```

Comment: I would run these as separate queries. There is no benefit to combining them.

Comment: It's `YEAR(CURDATE())`, the **ANSI-92** explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1992) as A_Very_Long_Time`, it's long past time you adopted it. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: No, you cannot combine the two queries easily because one displays results at row level, the other aggregates data.